# Sales Order Grid - Can't export custom columns

Tags: magento-enterprise, sales-order, export, order-grid

I've added the a few columns to the `sales_flat_order_grid`table.
The values are obtained in these two events `sales_order_resource_init_virtual_grid_columns` (using addVirtualGridColumn() ) and `sales_order_resource_update_grid_records` (updating the table values for some more complex joins).

```
<add_order_grid_column_handle>
    <reference name="sales_order.grid">
        <action method="addColumnAfter">
            <columnId>product_names</columnId>
            <arguments>
                <header>Product(s) Name(s)</header>
                <index>product_names</index>
                <type>text</type>
            </arguments>
            <after>created_at</after>
        </action>
        [...]
    </reference>
</add_order_grid_column_handle>

<adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
    <update handle="add_order_grid_column_handle" />
</adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
<adminhtml_sales_order_index>
    <update handle="add_order_grid_column_handle" />
</adminhtml_sales_order_index>
```

However, when exporting a csv of the grid, it doesn't include the custom columns.

I found that the file is loaded using the grid block like this:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/sales_order_grid');
```

But that, for some reason, is not loading the layout update I have written above, so the new columns are not used...

Is there any settings, or layout handle to add to this columns, so they are also used in the exported csv?

Comment: Is it your error solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid export is a different controller action, so the layout handle would be different, something like `adminhtml_sales_order_exportCsv` (didn't check if this is the exact handle). However, `exportCsvAction` doesn't seem to call `loadLayout` so probably using layout updates here wouldn't work.

From what I could tell by briefly looking at the code, there are three options, none of them extremely clean:

1. Create a custom grid extending `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` and add your logic to the `_prepareColumns` and `_prepareCollection` methods, then replace the core grid with the custom one
2. Overwrite the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` block and add your logic in `_prepareColumns` and `_prepareCollection`.
3. Overwrite the `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController` controller, `exportCsvAction` and call `addColumn` on the `$grid` block object to add your columns

Comment: Thanks. I went with option 3. Calling the same methods as in the layout, but in plain old php. Like so:

`$grid->addColumnAfter(
            'product_names',
            array(
                'header'    => "Product(s) Name(s)",
                'index'     => "product_names",
                'type'      => 'text',
            ),
            'created_at'
        );`

Comment: @ Adi : I am using this method https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/171754/51361        for adding custom field on sales order grid. but when i export,  the custom added column values not exported, how can i solve this error.